# How can i remove the red border from this div when clicked?

Tags: css, html

I am using font awesome icons inside a div. When clicked, I change the color to blue. However, I don't want the red border that appears when clicked. How to remove it?

[image]

### HTML

```
   <div class="row tile-container"> 
      <div class="tile-art search"  (click)="changeSearchClass();" 
       [ngClass]="clicksearch ? 'blue': 'search'" routerLink="/app-quotation">
            <i class="fas fa-search fa-lg"></i>
      </div>
   </div>
```

### CSS

```
 .tile-container{
  box-shadow: 1px 2px;
  color: lightgrey;
 }

 .search{
   padding-top:10px;
 }

 .blue{
   color:blue;
 }
```

Comment: It will be helpful if  you post css and picture of the div with red color.

Comment: Just a note, it's bad practice to remove this altogether. It's there for a reason; accessibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help

```
.tile-art:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: A dot to be added in front of tile-art. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS outline 0 to this class

```
.tile-art, .tile-art i {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
changeSearchClass(){ this.clicked = !this.clicked; }
```

and in your html

```
  <div class="tile-art search"  (click)="changeSearchClass();" [style.border]="clicked ?  none :'red' "
       [ngClass]="clicksearch ? 'blue': 'search'" routerLink="/app-quotation">
            <i class="fas fa-search fa-lg"></i>
      </div>
```